# Obtain score data from MatLab cascade object detector

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, cascade, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

I have trained a cascade object detector in MatLab. On my test images, it is putting bounding boxes around multiple regions of interest (ROIs), whereas I only want to find the single best match. I.e: the ROI with the highest score. How can I either:

1) restrict the detector to one bounding box over the highest scoring ROI?

OR

2) extract the score data from the detector, so I can manually pick the best result?

I understand this is trivial using the built in HOG person detector, but I have not found a way of doing it using custom detectors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score can't be extracted from cascade object detector. See this answer for more details:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/154044-how-to-get-confidence-values-for-detections-from-vision-cascadeobjectdetector-system-object